# Construct messages limited to a certain size from individual elements of varying size

Tags: java, string

I have N input messages that can vary in size entirely, and I need to generate a set of output messages that musn't be more than 500 characters. So, I should keep appending input messages together into a single output message until those are too big. It is possible that an input message is more than 500 characters, in which case I just split them down into as many output messages I need.

I wrote the code but it is very verbose and somewhat hard to follow. The logic is essentially that I keep adding to an outputMessage until adding more would make it too big, and then I just ship off what's currently in the outputMessage and start fresh with a new outputMessage. How should this be coded?

```
List<String> outputMessages;
StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (String inputMessage : inputMessages) {
  if (inputMessage.length() + outputBuilder.length() > 500 && outputBuilder.size() >= 0) {
    outputMessages.add(outputBuilder.toString());
    outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  }

  if (inputMessage.length() < 500) {
    outputBuilder.append(inputMessage);
  } else {
    Iterable<String> chunks = Splitter.fixedLength(500).split(inputMessage);
    for (String chunk : chunks) {
      outputMessages.add(chunk);
    }
    outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  }
}

if (outputBuilder.length() > 0) {
  outputMessages.add(outputBuilder.toString());
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to join all of the input messages into a single message, then use the `Splitter.fixedLength(500)`?

Comment: Then I'd potentially just be spitting down the middle of a word or a message.